# Big O: Reduce complexety order (list comprehension)

Tags: python, big-o, list-comprehension, census

I am trying to read out some census data. It consists out of ~53 mo lines and one of my function seems to increase the calculation time quadratically. I want to filter all the regions that have district heating. This little list comprehension makes the calculation time explode:

```
selection_dh = [x in ids_dh for x in ids_all]
```

ids_dh is a list of the region IDs that contain district heating, ids_all is a list of all the region IDs. ids_dh is roughly one tenth of the length of ids_all.

Any idea of how to make this code quicker?

Thanks!

```
census_dh= census_all.loc[census_all.Expression== "District Heating", :]

ids_all = list(census_all.Grid_ID_100m)
ids_dh = list(census_dh.Grid_ID_100m)

selection_dh = [x in ids_dh for x in ids_all]
```

Comment: "ds_dh is a list of the region ID" Here's the problem. Make it a `set` instead.

Comment: as far as I know, list membership testing is linear, change that to a set that have a optimized membership testing that is almost constant.

Comment: also, there is no need to make the list `ids_all` first, use the `census_all.Grid_ID_100m` directly in the comprehension

Comment: Thanks! Creating a `set` out of ids_dh made it 100 times faster!

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
selection_dh = np.isin(ids_all, ids_dh)
```

Comment: He wanted to speedup his list comprehension. Whatever the two lists are, `np.isin` does exaclty what his list comprehension is doing, and it is definitely faster on large lists. Why shouldn't it provide an answer?